# Merging multiple files and saving them by appending the file names

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have following data frames,

```
 Subtpe_sam_ID
 Subtype_sam_REL
 Subytpe_sam_ph
 Tab_sam_ID
 Tab_sam_REL
 Tab_sam_ph

Subtype.sam_ID.head()
chr start end ratio name 
ch1 334   456  0.1  SAP
chr2 789  788  0.6  SOP
```

and

```
`Tab_sam_ID.head()`
  chr start end cgid
  chr1 334  456 cgt780
  chr4 789  0.7 cg899
  chr2 789  788 cg899
```

and my desired output, for the above example, must a file same as `Tab_subtype_sam_ID_merge`

and it should look like,

```
Tab_subtype_sam_ID_merge.head() #as the name of the saved file

chr start end ratio name cgid
chr1 334  456 0.1 SAP  cgt780
```

And so I wrote the following piece of code for this,

```
path         = './Analysis/' 
files        = os.listdir(path)
Tab          = [os.path.join(path,i) for i in files if i.startswith('Tab')]  
path           = '/' 
files          = os.listdir(path)
Sub          = [os.path.join(path,i) for i in files if i.startswith('Subtype')]

for tab,homer in zip(Tab,Sub):
   df1=pd.read_csv(homer,sep='\t')
   df2=pd.read_csv(tab,sep='\t')
   name1 = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(homer))
   name2 = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(tab))
```

The logic to merge the files if column `start` and `chr` match from both Tab and subtype data frames.

But from here I couldn't figure out how could I merge two files based on their names, so I would have 3 resulting data frames.  For example, if data frame Subtpe_sam_ID is equal to Tab_sam_ID (here I mean the last part of the string is equal to each of these data frames, ie, ID, and ID) then merge on columns chr and Start. And then save with a common name.

All data frames starting with Subtype have the same columns in the same order and so as for Tab_*.

```
> if basename(name1)==basename(name2)
>           merge=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['chr','Start'])
>           dirname=os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath(filename))
>           merge.to_csv(dirname +merge+ name, sep='\t',index=False)
```

Any suggestions or help would be great..!!!!

Comment: Why not sort both lists? Wouldn't they be element-wise ordered matches then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this way:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = 'E:/mypc/tab_data/'
files = os.listdir(path)
Tab = [os.path.join(path,i) for i in files if i.startswith('Tab')]  

path = 'E:/mypc/subtype_data/' 
files = os.listdir(path)
Sub = [os.path.join(path,i) for i in files if i.startswith('Subtype')]

dirname = "E:/mypc/output/"

for i in Tab:
    for j in Sub:
        if "_".join(j.split("/")[-1].split("_")[1:]) == "_".join(i.split("/")[-1].split("_")[1:]):
        name = i.split("/")[-1].split("_")[0] + "_" + j.split("/")[-1]
        f = [j,i]
        df1=pd.read_csv(f[0])
        df2=pd.read_csv(f[1])
        merged_df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['chr','start'], suffixes=('','_')).T.drop_duplicates().T
        merged_df.to_csv(dirname + name , index=False)
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for the answer, but after the if loop nothing seems to work. I mean the df1 and df2 is empty and so the merged_df variable.  I am wondering why you are transposing merged_df ?

Comment: Sorry now it works, with a small chnag ein if loop as the real names are little diferent from my primary question, if j.split("/")[-1].split("_")[-1] == i.split("/")[-1].split("_")[-1]:

Comment: pd.merge creates duplicate columns for **end** column (i.e. end_x and end_y) so to get rid of it I use **T.drop_duplicates().T**.